# How to override the computed style in css?

Tags: css

The computed style for the specific label element is below,

[image]

This has been taken from firebug.

Here the issue is, ".text-ct-modified" class should be apply for the label instead of ".x-form-cb-label" class.

some how ".text-ct-modified" has been overridden , even i have given "!important to the class"

```
.text-ct-modified {
    font-weight: bold !important;
}
```

Is there any way to solve this ?

Comment: Show us the relevant HTML and CSS code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way would be to declare `.text-ct-modified` at the bottom of that style sheet where `.x-form-cb-label` exists. This will override it without declaring `!important`.

If it is generated dynamically, use `CSS Selectors` i.e parent child or adjacent sibling to take inheritance from that parent or its adjacent sibling and override it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the access of the element like DIV or SPAN or any other, where the class was applied, add an ID and paste the ID before the class. Like

```
#sectionID .text-ct-modified {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```